# How to access multiple contexts in javascript function (React.Component class method)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I have React component, which renders 3th party HoC `HotTable`.
`HotTable` have method `afterValidate` on it.

I am passing `handleAfterValidate` function to `HotTable`.
The problem is that `handleAfterValidate` should have access to `HotTable` instance and at the same time access to `HotTableWrapper` instance (see code below).

By default `this` inside `handleAfterValidate` refers to `HotTable` instance.
If I bind handler to React instance then I loose access to `HotTable` instance, but I need them both.

Is it possible to have access to both contexts in this case ?

```
class HotTableWrapper extends React.Component {
processCell(row, col) {
    // do something
}

handleAfterValidate(row, prop) {
    const col = this.propToCol(prop); // 'this' should refer to HotTable instance 
    this.processCell(row, col); // 'this' should refer to HotTableWrapper class instance
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <HotTable afterValidate={this.handleAfterValidate} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: you can bind to this and use ref to controll HotTable

Comment: This is good idea, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use currying function approach. If you have lodash on board, then you can do it like this:

```
class HotTableWrapper extends React.Component {
    processCell(row, col) {
        // do something
    }

    handleAfterValidate(wrapper, row, prop) {
        const col = this.propToCol(prop); // 'this' should refer to HotTable instance 
        wrapper.processCell(row, col); // 'this' should refer to HotTableWrapper class instance
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <HotTable afterValidate={_.curry(this.handleAfterValidate)(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#curry
If you don't have lodash, just google it how to implement helper for currying.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is having the `handleAfterValidate` code directly defined in the `HotTable` component and passing `processCell` as a prop with the scope on `HotTableWrapper`.

so in `HotTable` you would have

```
handleAfterValidate(wrapper, row, prop) {
    const col = this.propToCol(prop);
    this.props.processCell(row, col);
}
```

and in the `HotTableWrapper` render method

```
<HotTable processCell={this.processCell.bind(this)}/>
```